# Case-Insensitive Property Binding Without Using JsonProperty in .NET Core

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, autorest

I have a `C# ASP.NET Core Web Api` app and `C# ASP.NET Core MVC` app

In this case, the `MVC` app calls the `API` app with a model like this (the client was generated via `AutoRest`):

```
var thing = await thingApi.ThingPost(new ThingModel { ThingID = ThingID });
```

At this point, I can debug to see that the `ThingID` is set with my value. When I debug the `API` app I can see that the property did not transfer over... property defined as such:

```
public long ThingID { get; set; }
```

However, when I decorate it with

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "thingID")]
```

Then the value is bound. I am trying to figure out how I can have it bind without having to decorate it with that attribute. Some kind of a case-insensitive resolver or something?

I've tried using:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

and

```
.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Without updating the client, both failed to resolve the property. The thing is that I don't want the client to change. It should be generated as it is now, but I want the value to be bound to the property regardless of the case in the client. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit... my model inherited from a `base class` (which I probably should have mentioned in my question) and my `base class` was decorated with:

```
[DataContract]
```

which obviously forces you to specify each of the properties you want exposed... so a bit of a duh moment.